Is one allowed to consult oil and egg demons?
On one hand, the Gemara Sanhedrin 101a states:

And one may not consult the words of demons on Shabbat. Rabbi Yosei says: Even during the week it is prohibited to consult demons. Rav Huna said: The halakha is in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yosei.

On the other hand it continues:

The Sages taught in a baraita: With regard to demons of oil and demons of eggs, i.e., demons consulted by means of oil and eggs, respectively, it is permitted to consult them; but it is futile to do so, due to the fact that they deceive. One may whisper an incantation for healing over oil that is in a vessel and one may not whisper an incantation over oil that is in one’s hand. Therefore, one may smear oil on his body from oil that is brought to him in another’s hand, and there is no concern that perhaps someone whispered over it; and one may not smear oil that is brought to him in a vessel, as perhaps someone whispered over it and it will cause him harm.

Therefore, it seems, that one can consult oil and egg demons, cannot s/he? What is the nature of the permission if any?

Are you asking if the gemara is wrong?

@shmosel No, I just wanted to make sure that's actually what it means.

Look, it’s not relevant to the question, but you do know that demons were banished from civilization, right? The Gemara’s discussions regarding how one can interact with demons is no longer applicable.

If you consult oil and egg demons at the same time, you must take care not to produce mayonnaise demons
